# Cancel the href case that not all the values filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a function that checks if the values ​​are filled by pressing the button, if not all complete I want to cancel the href of the button.

I tried this:

```
<a href="XXX.html"  data-role="button" data-transition="none"
                data-theme="b" onclick="Check(); return false;" data-icon="forward" data-iconpos="left">
            </a>
```

And also tried to return false from the function.

Both ways do not work!

Which is another way I can cancel the href?

I tried these things:

```
function Check(event) {

    if (Testing the values ​​filled) {
     //Do something
    }
    else {
//One of the two following lines
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#xxx .ui-btn").unbind('click');
    }
```

}

Even those things do not work, he comes to else but it does not cancel the href

Comment: Can you please post more of your HTML (showing what values need to be filled) as well as the JS that you are using to validate the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
function Check() {
  if (Testing the values ​​filled) {
   //Do something
  }
  else {
   $("#xxx .ui-btn").attr('href', "javascript:void(0)");
  }
```

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/bTXFq/1/)**

Bind event using jquery

```
$('a[data-role=button]').click(Check);
```

Javascript function

```
function Check(event)
{
   //Your code
   if(condition) // some condition if required.
     event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: You can put it out side condition.

Comment: It really comes to   event.preventDefault() but he continues to link

Comment: I have added live demo, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unbind`,

```
function Check(){
   if(condition){
      $('a[data-role=button]').unbind('click');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use die() event instead of unbind event.

```
function Check(){
  if(condition){
      $('a[data-role=button]').die('click');
  }
}
```